# Should I use multiple apps in one Firebase project just to use the same authentication system?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage

For example, Google has different-purpose products that use the same authentication system like Google Photos, Google Drive, Google Play, Google Meet, etc. Each product of these serves a different purpose, but they all share the same authentication system.

I want to do the same for my apps. I've like 3 apps, but I want them to share the same authentication system, so if user 1 creates an account in app 1, they could sign in to app 2, or app 3 without re-creating the account. So is that possible using Firebase Authentication? I saw that each Firebase project can hold up to 30 apps. What if I wanted more at some point? For things like Realtime Database, I was planning to create:

```
General
  Data is shared across all 3 apps.
App 1 
  Data-only app 1 needs.
App 2 
  Data-only app 2 needs.
App 3 
  Data-only app 3 needs.
```

But for things like Cloud Storage, I'm not sure since there's no way for nesting stuff there.

Any ideas? Is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Rainy mentioned in his answer, yes, that is perfectly possible. The best part is that you can create up to 30 apps within a single project no matter what the platform is, Android, iOS, or web.

> I want to do the same for my apps. I've like 3 apps, but I want them to share the same authentication system.

Yes, all apps will share the same authentication and databases, Firestore or the Realtime Database.

Answer (score 1):

of course as you said you can create multiple(as described up to 30) app within a same project and they all will/can be authenticated by the same auth credentials

but for more then 30 you should contact firebase-support (read  [apps-per-project](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#apps-per-project) ) and they might help or guide you for the same ,

just for as a suggestion if your app shares same features then it will be better to consider consolidating them into a single app within your Firebase project.

Comment: So about your last line, you mean cop/paste config across more than 1 app?

Comment: not exactly , i mean if talk about authentication then let just keep him loged-in for rest of the flow and if he is not suppose to access or use some part of app use guards for that also best on top to keep your firebase auth rules really tough and robust.